# Ruby on Rails, Using sort on each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use sort on each do. I get the error

wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

I understand that I cannot daisy chain them together. Does anyone know another methods of getting this done.

```
  <% Category.sort(:id).limit(4).each do |type| %>
      <%= type.name %>
  <% end %>
```

The result I am aiming for is to have all categories listed from a to z.

Comment: try `{` instead of `do`, and `}`, instead of `end`

Comment: If `Category` is an ActiveRecord model, you want `.order(:id).limit(4)`.

Comment: Is Category an array or AR ?

Comment: @meagar, Thanks alot. I actually did try .order but I used id instead of :id. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the `Category` is an `Active Record` then

`<% Category.order(:id).limit(4).each do |type| %>`   would do the trick.

Comment: thanks. But if you look under the comments, you will notice you provide the same answer as meagar

Comment: oh,I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Pavan What does the `.limit(4)` do here?
And how do I do the sorting desceding?

Comment: @TasosAnesiadis It's been a while but maybe this will help someone else. `.limit(4)` shows only 4 last records from the query result. You can use `.order("created_at desc")`. Replace `created at` with whatever you want to take into account for sorting.